# How to find the relationship between two variables using regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python

I have a Raspberry Pi hooked up to a sensor, which will send a data to the device every second. As you may have guessed, what I want is to find a relation between this independent variable time and the dependent sensory data.

First of all, I know I have to find what kind of regression model would best fit for my data, either linear, exponential, or other, but I don't know how I could choose without directly looking at how the data is distributed, which I can't because the data keeps changing over time.

Then after I found the regression model I have to train it with my data. Lastly, I could extract the constants to find my equation describing the phenomena.

I am using Python for the implementation, so if you have any thoughts on how I could do this, I'd appreciate you sharing it with me.

To just give glimpse of what kind of data is being gathered,

```
y1 = [139, 136, 151, 158, 161, 165, 169, 173, 180, 184, 182, 184, 187, 189, 191, 198, 203, 208, 206, 205, 210, 223, 229, 236, 181, 185, 182, 185, 191, 208, 235, 247, 266, 242, 217, 226, 227, 231, 238, 246, 244] 
y2 = [262, 258, 261, 257, 257, 256, 255, 253, 250, 244, 244, 241, 239, 238, 237, 234, 232, 230, 228, 228, 227, 225, 225, 226, 273, 280, 286, 295, 300, 305, 312, 325, 337, 338, 335, 342, 355, 364, 371, 407, 430]
t = [5.01068115234375, 5.073676586151123, 5.131673812866211, 5.188669681549072, 5.248665809631348, 5.308662176132202, 5.364659070968628, 5.416654348373413, 5.463649272918701, 5.513647079467773, 5.582644462585449, 5.641641855239868, 5.700639486312866, 5.762631893157959, 5.820631265640259, 5.879623174667358, 5.939624071121216, 5.998619318008423, 6.057611703872681, 6.115608215332031, 6.174605369567871, 6.2236034870147705, 6.284603118896484, 6.341594457626343, 6.392592906951904, 6.447590351104736, 6.505584716796875, 6.560581207275391, 6.614629745483398, 6.682576894760132, 6.743568181991577, 6.80156683921814, 6.862563848495483, 6.92155909538269, 6.983552932739258, 7.034592151641846, 7.102548837661743, 7.160544157028198, 7.219539642333984, 7.290534973144531, 9.228410243988037]
```

where y1 and y2 are the data from the pi at different runs of the program, and t is the time in seconds.  But if the script was to be run again a different x-y pair would be found so it isn't reliable to decide a regression model from seeing this.

Comment: Can you please post some preliminary data? I have run Python fitting software on my Pi, and have some Python code you can use if Python is OK.

Comment: That is great, I am working with python. And it doesn't matter even if the computation power of the pi isn't good enough to process the data i can run the modeling on my computer.

Comment: I As noted, I have run my zunzun.com open source Python curve and surface fitting web site on a Raspberry Pi. The installation instructions are in the source code's README file at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/zunzunsite3/src/master/README.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can treat this as a two stage research project. First discover what transformations best fit the data, then use it.

You will need to discover:

- Is it cyclic, with amplitude, frequency, and phase modulation,
  Multiple components? each with overtones? 
  Scaling: linear, power,log, exponentiation?

The following articles from the late 1960's and early 1970's showed how to calculate a time varying impulse response by doing linear regressions using a sliding window. (I implemented this in real time on a Digital Scientific META-4 emulating and IBM 1130/1800, so I am sure a Raspberry Pi is fast enough. It has floating point support, so you will not need to use fixed point arithmetic as I did back then.)  You can then transform from the time domain to the frequency domain at your convenience off line.

- Wierwille, "A theory for optimal deterministic characterization of time-varying human operator dynamics"
- Jin-ichi Nagumo, Shunsuke Sato, Atsuhiko Noda, "Real-Time Display System of Response Characteristics of Manual Tracking Systems"

Your requirement like a single signal analysis, rather than these articles’ black-box system identification exercise, trying to identify a transformation.
Alternatively, you could use FFT and work in the frequency domain.

Comment: I suggest you inspect scatterplots of the posted data before recommending data transformation.

Comment: I almost agree. I suggest that the **owner** of the data inspect scatter plots. However, I also suggest trying transformations. Depending on the domain, it is very hard to look at a scatter plot or even a continuous curve and discern visually whether it is best described as a log or fractional power curve.  

If I recall from a course on sensory processes decades ago, It was originally thought that sound intensity sensation was logarithmic, but later discovered to be, like most senses, on a power curve.